# Logging who purged a queue in MSMQ

Tags: msmq

I'm looking for a way to know who/what purged a queue (specifically Errors queue) in MSMQ. I know that messages were purged because they end up in "Transactional dead-letter messages" with the Type set to "Acknowledgement QueuePurged". But is there any way to know which AD user (or process?) triggered this? Nothing seems to be logged in Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

There will be nothing in the security event viewer as there is no auditing enabled by default.

[Auditing Message Queuing Objects](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754324%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)